# Get all match records based on their last child in Django ORM?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

I have these two classes in my `models.py` :

```
class BaseObject(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['create_date']


class Person(BaseObject):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)

class Driver(Person):
    balance = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Position(BaseObject):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
```

As you can see each driver may have several positions by passing the time.

I want a query using Django ORM that gives me last position of each driver, imagine that i receive a `latitude` and `longitude` from client and wish to return all cars that is near.

I tried this :

```
 radius = 5

 drivers = Driver.objects.filter(position__latitude__range=(data.get('latitude') - radius, data.get('latitude') + radius))\
                         .filter(position__longitude__range=(data.get('longitude') - radius, data.get('longitude') + radius))\
```

But the problem is that I get a single driver several time based on their positions.
Now i just want to get the drivers with their last update position, not their previous ones. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea to get distinct Drivers (That's why I understand you're trying to get) with it's last Position.

First, order by the Driver Positions, from the last one to the first one.
`.order_by('-person__create_date',)`

Then use [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) in order to get only Driver per position (the last one):
`.distinct()`

---

And here's a second proposition, to get every driver with it's last position (thanks to your automatic 'create_date' and [Django Annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) ):

```
my_drivers = Driver.objects.all().annotate(last_position=Max('person__create_date'))

my_drivers[0].last_position
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17, 14, 25, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Here, every item in the `my_drivers` queryset will have a `last_position` attribute.

---

And finally, to @mehrdad-pedramfar request, an idea to get a `last_position` from a Driver.

```
class Driver(Person):
    balance = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def get_last_position(self):
        return Position.object.filter(person=self).order_by('-create_date').first()
```

I haven't tried it against your code, but the idea is here. It would cost a DB call each time it is called. 
The result is the last `Position` object for the current `Driver` :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i dont want to get only Driver per position. i want to get last position of each driver. can you suggest anything for this ?@ppython

Comment: Here, @mehrdad-pedramfar

Comment: Here, @mehrdad-pedramfar, I added a second idea with annotate! this one should do more precisely what you need! Keep me updated.

Comment: dear @ppython, the only thing matters now is `Max('person__create_date')` . i want that last_position to be a row of my Position table , not a date

Comment: Well, maybe you don't really want `last_position` as a row of your DB, but as an attribute/method of your `Position` class :) ? If so ... I'll provide a 3rd idea in my answer.